# extract results after Post query

Tags: r, post, screen-scraping

I am trying to extract automatically electricity offers from this [site](http://www.qenergy.com.au/Electricity-Offers).Once I set the postcode (i.e: 300) , I can download(manually) the pdf files

I am using `httr` package :

```
library(httr)
qr<- POST("http://www.qenergy.com.au/What-Are-Your-Options",
     query=list(postcode=3000))
res <- htmlParse(content(qr))
```

The problem is that the files urls are not in the query response. Any help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
library(httr)
qr<- POST("http://www.qenergy.com.au/What-Are-Your-Options", 
          encode="form", 
          body=list(postcode=3000))
res <- content(qr)
pdfs <- as(res['//a[contains(@href, "pdf")]/@href'], "character")
head(pdfs)
# [1] "flux-content/qenergy/pdf/VIC price fact sheet jemena distribution zone business/Jemena-Freedom-Biz-5-Day-Time-of-Use-A210.pdf"  
# [2] "flux-content/qenergy/pdf/VIC price fact sheet jemena distribution zone business/Jemena-Freedom-Biz-7-Day-Time-of-Use-A250.pdf"  
# [3] "flux-content/qenergy/pdf/VIC price fact sheet jemena distribution zone business/Jemena-Freedom-Biz-Single-Rate-CL.pdf"          
# [4] "flux-content/qenergy/pdf/VIC price fact sheet jemena distribution zone business/Jemena-Freedom-Biz-Single-Rate.pdf"             
# [5] "flux-content/qenergy/pdf/VIC price fact sheet united energy distribution zone business/United-Freedom-Biz-5-Day-Time-of-Use.pdf"
# [6] "flux-content/qenergy/pdf/VIC price fact sheet united energy distribution zone business/United-Freedom-Biz-7-Day-Time-of-Use.pdf"
```